# ''grub-install failed, this is a fatal error' during the installation of second Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, mint

I am working with a computer that has Windows and Xubuntu operational systems. Besides that, I wanted to install Linux Mint 20 (then I tried with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) alongside these two operating systems. So, I created an EFI, a home, and a root partition before moving on to installation. Everything was going perfectly but when It starts to install 'grub-install' it gives the fatal error that mentioned.

It is the first time that I install the second ubuntu in one machine and I did not face this error before. I have tried almost everything what they have suggested as a solution from other questions, but it did not work for me.

Here is the partition list, shown by running `sudo fdisk -L`:

[image: sudo fdisk -L outpu]

I would like to know if I am missing a special part during or before the installation.

Comment: Your legacy system does not need an efi partition.  But if you boot in legacy, not sure why the grub-install fails.

Comment: I turned off (unselect) the legacy mode on the BIOS settings.

Comment: Windows in legacy means you should install Ubuntu in legacy.  Maybe the error was because the EFI partition you created is a logical parition, I'm not even sure that's a valid EFI, so the grub-efi install then failed. Be aware with two Linux systems, the last one updated may take over the grub menu.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I do not know what is legacy means actually. But, I realized there must be a mismatch version of GRUBs between old-ubuntu and the new one.

Comment: Legacy just means pre-UEFI.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI The UEFI capable machines can be set to boot the old MBR way, (the legacy way). Disk partitioning may be either DOS (the old way) or gpt (the new way), but only Windows ties that to the boot mode -- it requires DOS for legacy and gpt for UEFI.